# Open Yahoo Finance Links data without going to the link

Tags: yahoo-finance

```
symbols = ['AAPL', 'MSFT', 'AMZN', 'GOOG', 'FB']

financials = {}

for symbol in symbols:

           financials[symbol] = ['https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/' + symbol + '/key-statistics?p=' + symbol]

print (financials)

data = pd.DataFrame()
```

When I execute, the result is below. I can click on each link and read the data, but I am wondering if it's possible to download the result page into CSV or Excel files without going to each link.

```
{'AAPL': ['https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/key-statistics?p=AAPL'], 'MSFT': ['https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/MSFT/key-statistics?p=MSFT'], 'AMZN': ['https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AMZN/key-statistics?p=AMZN'], 'GOOG': ['https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/GOOG/key-statistics?p=GOOG'], 'FB': ['https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/FB/key-statistics?p=FB']}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yep, the `requests` library will do the trick

```
import requests
s = requests.get(url).content
```

there's a nice tutorial you can follow here:

https://towardsdatascience.com/downloading-historical-stock-prices-in-python-93f85f059c1f